# Connecting Google Adwords with QlikView

Tags: google-ads-api, qlikview

I'm working in a project with Google Adwords and QlikView, the goal is to connect Adwords to QlikView so that I can import the data from Adwords to QlikView.

If you have an idea to do this, please answer me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not mind a paid-for solution, there is a ready-made solution from [QVSource](http://www.qvsource.com) for Google AdWords that you can use as a standard connector (similar to ODBC Connector) to load data into QlikView.

You can find more details here: http://wiki.qvsource.com/Dedicated-Google-AdWords-Connector-for-QlikView.ashx

Disclaimer: I am not affliated with QVSource or its subsiduaries in any way.

Comment: thank you for your answer, did you have an idea about how much will cost me?

Comment: @user2244285: Unfortunately not, QVSource appears not to publish their pricing information on their site.

Comment: Hi again, there's any other ways to connect Adwords with Qlikview, without using the connector of QVSource?

Comment: Regarding QVSource - you can request a quote using the form linked from this page: http://www.qvsource.com/Purchase/Overview

The connector (http://wiki.qvsource.com/Dedicated-Google-AdWords-Connector-for-QlikView.ashx) lets you run AWQL queries.

Comment: can i work with adwords API? or there's no other solutions but the QVSource Connector?

Comment: I am not sure if this still helps,
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/connectors/Subsystems/Web_Connectors_help/Content/Data-Source-Connectors/Google-AdWords-Connector.htm